# Share a specific Kibana dashboard by guest token

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I am using Kibana to create dashboards for my clients and want to share these dashboards with each respective client.

The use case is that when a customer creates an account on my website, I need to automatically create a dashboard on Kibana, and the customer should be able to access their dashboard. The challenge here is that I have many customers and do not want to create Kibana accounts, manage permissions for each individual.

I have previously used Superset and found that it can share dashboards through a guest token by creating a guest token and adding the corresponding dashboard view permission to that token. The token expires after a certain period, eliminating the need for creating accounts, managing permissions, and handling individual accounts.

So, my question is: Is there a way for Kibana to share dashboards through a temporary guest token similar to Superset?

The following link provides information about Superset guest tokens: [Superset Guest Token Overview](https://www.restack.io/docs/superset-knowledge-superset-guest-token-overview), and I am looking for a similar feature in Kibana.